# Save and Get $priority of item in Firebase collection AngularFire 0.6.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Let's say I have a collection of items

```
var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/items");  
$scope.items = $firebase(itemsRef);
```

And I want to save a new item to the collection with a `$priority`

```
$scope.items["thing"] = {name:'The Thing'};
$scope.items["thing"].$priority = 1;
$scope.items.$save("thing");
```

So far so good - I can see the new item in my collection.

Now let's fetch it and figure out what `$priority` I just assigned to it:

```
var thingRef = new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/items/thing");  
$scope.thing = $firebase(thingRef);
$scope.thing.$on("loaded", function() {
  console.log($scope.thing);
});
```

Which shows us our Firebase object in the console **without** a `$priority` assigned to it.

However if we do this:

```
//After saving the "thing" $priority
$scope.items.$on("loaded", function() {
  console.log($scope.items);
});
```

You will see the child node and its `$priority`

**What is the correct way to both save and get priorities for a Firebase collection item?**

Comment: That should work, unless the call to save() is calling `update` which doesn't persist priorities. Can you try using the `orderByPriority` filter to see if the priorities are reflected in the array that is returned by the filter?

Comment: @Anant Well what's interesting is that when I `console.log($scope.items)` after a `$scope.items.$on("loaded")` callback I see the `$priority` attached as a property of the `thing` child node. Is a `$priority` only returned when fetching parents that contain children with a `$priority`?

Comment: Ah, that could indeed be the case. We see if getPriority() returns anything while parsing a snapshot and if one isn't present, we won't include it for that particular node.

Comment: @Anant Now that we've established there is in fact a `$priority` being saved to `thing` I think were back to the original question which is --- should you be able to directly fetch the `$priority` for `thing` using the `items/thing` ref?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. If you aren't, that's likely to be a bug. Could you file one under angularFire on Github? Thanks!

Comment: @Anant https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/243

Comment: Thanks - we'll get it fixed ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug which has since been resolved:
https://github.com/firebase/angularFire/issues/243